# How can I create a new CSS file the right way in Dreamweaver cc?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

On the dreamweaver cc's CSS designer panel, when I click the plus icon and "create a new CSS file, it always appears in the html code:
<

Should the right order be href type rel?
I just can't point the new CSS file to the html file unless I can the order,href rel type, to the order, href type rel.

Did anybody come across the same problem in DW?

Comment: After you click the plus click on "create a new CSS" file, then click "browse" and choose where you want to save the file and what to name it, leave the "add as" set to the default "link." Once you've done that it will automatically be linked in the `head` of your html.

Comment: Thanks APAD1, I tried your suggestion and the problem still remains.

Comment: The CSS is linked to the head of my html but I can't style the HTML unless I change the order of the elements in to "href, type, rel" instead of "href, rel, type".

Comment: You have to add the css in the new file you created